# Anywhere transition to a new view after returning from a different view

Tags: maximo-anywhere

We have a weird customization in Work Execution where we need 3 levels of one to many from work order (Hierarchy is Work Order->Custom Checklist Object (they review before starting work on a work order)->Custom Hazard Object->Custom Precaution Object). Each of these objects have three views (a list, a detail view, and a creation view).

Right now, when a user creates a hazard it returns to the checklist object. We want to open the detail view of the hazard so someone can easily modify the precautions that were added or add new ones (instead of having to go from the new checklist object->hazard list->hazard detail). Having the precautions editable directly on the add hazard screen causes a bunch of other issues so it's best to force the user to create a hazard before allowing them to add precautions.

On the create button in the New Hazard view we can add a click event and use eventContext.ui.show("ViewName") and display our hazard detail view (which works). The problem is when they save the hazard detail view, the this.ui.hideCurrentView() closes the Hazard Detail View and returns back to the Add New Hazard view since that was the last view displayed. We've also learned that if someone uses the back button in the hazard detail view it causes the hazard to be deleted (instead of just discarding the changes they made in the hazard detail view).

What we really want is when the user clicks the create hazard button, that it returns to the new checklist object view and then based on a flag that we've set on the object (to determine that a new hazard was added) open the hazard detail view. We've tried render & show event handler events on the new checklist view and on buttons and textboxes in the view and our code fires but it seems like because it's in the process of transitioning from the add hazard view to the add checklist view that it won't allow new UI transitions.

Is there a way for us to essentially inject that the hazard detail view should be what we return to from the add hazard view? Perhaps by modifying the viewHistory in the UserInterface?

Answer (score 0):

You can probably dynamically modify the view stack, to remove the Add New Hazard view from the stack.  If you look at some of our platform code you can see how to do that.  A little bit of sample code..

```
var viewHistory = eventContext.ui.viewHistory;
var previousView = viewHistory[viewHistory.length-2];
```

Lemme know if this usecase comes up more often, we maybe should formalize this API for you.

UPDATE: in 7.6 we do have this method for you, UserInterface.returnToView(viewId)